# JavaScript error: unexpected identifier, help pls?

Tags: javascript

i am using a javascript to get data and put it into a table, i dont know where i have gone wrong? please help!

my code is:

```
function getSOCsForJobTitle() {
var searchtitle = s("#search-input").val();
var apiurl = "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/search?q="
var apicall = apiurl + searchtitle;

s.get(apicall.function (data) s.each(data.function (i.e) {
        var tablerow = s("<tr></tr>");
        tablerow.append("<td>" + e.title + "/td>");
        tablerow.append("<td>" + e.SOC + "/td>");
        s("#SOCstable").append(tablerow);
    });
});
}

s(function () {
// this gets called when the page loads
s("#search-go") onclick(getSOCsForJobTitle);
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain where exactly is your problem / question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> apicall.function (data) s.each(data.function (i.e) {
> ```

First:

`apicall` is a string, so it won't have a `function` property. Presumably you are trying to pass it and the function as separate arguments to `s.get`. You need a comma, not a period.

```
apicall, function (data) s.each(data.function (i.e) {
```

Second:

It looks like you are trying to pass an anonymous function as the second argument. The syntax for that is:

```
function (arg) { 
   // expressions
}
```

You are missing the `{`.

```
apicall, function (data) {
    s.each(data.function (i.e) {
```

Third:

It looks like you've made exactly the same error for what you are trying to pass to `s.each`.

Comment: ive done that and got this, but it now says: unexpected token var.         s.get(apicall, function (data) { 
  s.each(data.function (i.e)
            var tablerow = s("<tr></tr>");
            tablerow.append("<td>" + e.title + "/td>");
            tablerow.append("<td>" + e.SOC + "/td>");
            s("#SOCstable").append(tablerow);

Comment: @Samy447 — See the section of this answer headed "third"

Comment: thanks that was relay helpfull

Answer (score 0):

1. `s` --> `$`
2. `s("#search-go") onclick` --> `$("#search-go").click`